# How do I assign a material to my imported OBJ file in the ThreeJS Editor

Tags: three.js

I'm testing a custom scene in ThreeJS.org/editor.  I've started with the Camera example scene as a template.  I want to add custom geometry to it.  When I import my OBJ file, the mesh appears in the editor with no problem, but there doesn't seem to be a way to import its material along with it. Instead, I went and manually assigned the correct texture map to the imported object's Material component.

In the editor, the texture map showed up and looked great after I added it manually, but when I pressed Play (or when I Exported or Published the scene) the texture map for that object was gone again.  I tried refreshing my window, and all changes I made to the material component were lost.

There must be something simple I've overlooked. Can anyone help?

Comment: The MTL loader is alive and well but the API is very specific about loading MTL files. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380403/how-to-use-objloader-and-mtlloader-in-three-js-r74-and-later) and [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html) for implementation examples.

Answer (score 0):

The OBJ format doesn't store material data; it uses a separate format, MTL, for that. Unfortunately, it seems that the Three.JS editor doesn't currently support MTL files.

Comment: Correct, but it does allow you to upload texture maps manually.  I just need to know what those maps are not being saved when I export or publish.