# How to use OBJLoader and MTLLoader in THREE.js r74 and later

Tags: three.js

It seems that [OBJMTLLoader has been removed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/ad41d295eeb6cb77cb56e931fea881fe71fcb6ab) recently (r74?), but I cannot track down any documentation on how to use the two replacement classes. Here is the current code I have (adapted from [Three.js Cookbook](https://github.com/josdirksen/threejs-cookbook/blob/master/02-geometries-meshes/02.14-use-objmtlloader-with-multiple-materials.html)):

```
<script src="../libs/three.r74.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>

<script>
var legoManMesh = null;
function init(){ /* Create my scene here */ }

var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load("../assets/models/lego.obj", "../assets/models/lego.mtl",
  function (obj) {
    legoManMesh = obj;
    init();
    }
  );
</script>
```

(BTW, when moving from r69 to r74 the above code fails with "TypeError: loader.setCrossOrigin is not a function")

---

**ADDITIONAL:**

The sample lego.mtl file here references a texture png using a relative path.

```
# Blender MTL File: 'LEGO Minifigure - Blendswap.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl Cap
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.990000 0.120000 0.120000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.00000
illum 2

newmtl Minifig
Ns 874.999998
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd ../textures/Mini-tex.png
```

Comment: Just look at the source [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r74/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js) and [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r74/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js). You can see they both have a `load` function with the second parameter being the callback function.

Comment: look at the example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is code that demonstrates how to load .obj and .mtl files in r74:

```
var mesh = null;

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( "https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/walt/" );
mtlLoader.load( 'WaltHead.mtl', function( materials ) {

  materials.preload();

  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
  objLoader.setPath( "https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/walt/" );
  objLoader.load( 'WaltHead.obj', function ( object ) {

    mesh = object;
    mesh.position.y = -50;
    scene.add( mesh );

  } );

} );
```

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/g2evz0q5/

Updated answer to reflect correction for completeness.

Comment: Thanks gaitat. I tried it and get a 404 on "threejs-cookbook/03-camera/undefined../textures/Mini-tex.png". I've updated my question to show that the mtl file has a png texture, that is kept in a relative path. The `undefined` in the 404 URL makes me think this might be solvable?

Comment: (P.S. It still fails to load even if I move the png in the same directory as the mtl file, and edit the mtl file to match. The 404 is now on "threejs-cookbook/03-camera/undefinedMini-tex.png" !)

Comment: Got it working: as well as `mtlLoader.setPath( "http://threejs.org/examples/obj/walt/" );` you need `mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( "http://threejs.org/examples/obj/walt/" );`

Comment: @gaitat Is there any way to provide a callback function to `materials.preload()`?  Because following the code provided here, if the material image is much larger than the `.obj` file, the object is still rendered before the textures are available.  It kind of renders the `.preload()` function worthless...

Comment: You would need to copy the MTLLoader in your own space and modify it to support this functionality. In there, there is a loadTexture method that has the arguments you require but they are not exposed.

Comment: Fiddle is broken.