# ThreeJS OBJMTLLoader renders object before textures are available

Tags: javascript, three.js

The `.load()` function allows the user to supply a callback function to be executed when the object has been loaded. However, it seems that this callback is executed after the .obj and .mtl files are loaded, but before the .mtl is parsed and texture images are present.  This results in the object being rendered without any textures.  Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem?

There is an [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1583) on GitHub that addresses this, but I do not see a solution posted there.

OBJMTLLoader example:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

loader.load( model_obj, model_mtl, function ( object ) {

    object.position.y = y_init;
    scene.add( object );
    render();
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded');

}, onProgress, onError );
```

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: @Vince Tried any of the options mentioned here in discussions? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1751

Comment: @pratikwebdev I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require modifications to the three.js source if at all possible.

Comment: @OliverQueen added sample code

Comment: Could you use a promise to wait for the whole thing to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move to r74. There the MTL loader and the OBJ loader are separated and there is even a `materials.preload();` to address this issue. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422599/1980846