# Three.JS - apply image textute to .OBJ

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm trying to add an image texture to an loaded .OBJ
now it looks like that
https://cuplate.com/ttt.php

I use MeshBasicMaterial to load my image as a texture. I used that for different geometry on ThreeJS

OBJ loader is like this

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( './test1.obj',function ( object ) {  
    object.traverse( function ( node ) {
    if ( node.isMesh) {
        node.material = materialOuter;          
    }

});
    scene.add( object );
});
```

the image doesnt show....
How should I place my image on the front side of this plate?

Comment: this is the pattern to use to load OBJ models with textures: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422599/1980846

Comment: I guess my OBJ is badly constructed. not working for me. 10x

Comment: can you create a fiddle?