# How to load .obj and .mtl file into a Vue component while using Vue CLI 3

Tags: html, css, vue.js, three.js, vue-cli-3

I am a VueJs and Three begginer so the code I have is mainly from copy paste.
I want to load a 3d file (.obj) and (.mtl) into a Vue component.
I  npm installed three and imported the loaders.

```html
<template>
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Three from 'three'
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js'
export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null,
      publicPath: 'process.env.BASE_URL',
      loader: null,
      loader2: null
     
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
        let container = document.getElementById('container');
//camera
        this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(70, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.01, 10);
        this.camera.position.z = 1;
//scene
        this.scene = new Three.Scene();
//obj loader
        this.loader = new OBJLoader();
        this.loader.load(`${this.publicPath}maquina1.obj`, (loadedObject) => {
        this.scene.add(loadedObject)
        console.log(loadedObject);})
//MMTLoader
        this.loader2 = new MTLLoader();
        this.loader2.load(`${this.publicPath}maquina1.mtl`, (loadedObject) => {
        this.scene.add(loadedObject)
        console.log(loadedObject);})
// Create and add AmbientLight.
//let light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
//this.scene.add(light);

//renderer
        this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
        container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
          },

    animate: function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      this.animate();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#container{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

I am getting a black square and the error  "THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. "

Also I think MTLLoader is not loading anything since what I get in console through console.log is an object with the majority of values with 0 or undefined

Also getting lots of warnings saying THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "" as if OBJLoader is returning html content instead of a 3d image

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are loading in files from the `three/examples/js/` folder, try loading all the loaders from the `three/examples/jsm/` folder. Why you did it for the DDSLoader, but not the others I am not sure.

eg..
Change:

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js'
import { DDSLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DDSLoader.js';
```

to

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js'
import { DDSLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DDSLoader.js';
```

**EDIT:**
Now you have edited the code in your question... the above answer is no longer valid :(

You wont see anything because you don't call renderer.render anywhere.

**EDIT**, Question changed again.
the line `this.scene.add(x.this.scene );` is wrong.
It should be `this.scene.add(x);`

change:

```
new OBJLoader().load( 'ecoponto/public/maquina1.obj', function (x) {
  this.scene.add(x.this.scene );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {console.error( error );} );
```

to

```
let loader = new OBJLoader();
loader.load('ecoponto/public/maquina1.obj', (loadedObject) => {
  this.scene.add(loadedObject);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr 2pha. Now I am not seeing any error in the browser but the 3d and mtl files are not being displayed yet. Any hints on what is missing?

Comment: You have to render the scene at least once after your models and textures are loaded (though often done in a requestAnimationFrame loop). I don't see anywhere in your code that does this.

Comment: Thank you Mr 2pha. I've added the requestAnimationFrame as you advised me to and now I get a black screen which is signal of progress. But still no file being loaded

Comment: Fix the indenting in the code sample in your question.. it's hard to read as it is.  I have a [vue.js + three.js project here](https://github.com/2pha/vue-three-shaders) which you can take a look at. Specifically in this case, the [scene component](https://github.com/2pha/vue-three-shaders/blob/master/src/components/Scene.vue).

Comment: Thank you Mr 2pha. I saw your examples, updated and idented my code. But still don't get it why the loader isn't working and I am getting the Cannot read property 'center' of undefined error

Comment: Do you know any example of using obj and mtl loader in a vue cli3 component? Because I don't want to create any object, just load a file that was already built in blender

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I don't want to create any object", the loader creates a javascript object so it can be added to your scene. `this.scene.add(x.this.scene );` is wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Mr 2pha .When I said "I don't want to create any object" I meant I didn't want to start a 3d model from 0, just rendering one that was already done. I've updated the code but still giving me the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined" 1000 times

Comment: Where does it say the error is? as in... what file and line

Comment: wait.. why do you have the lines `this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(material); this.scene.add(this.mesh);`.... remove those. The [Mesh object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh) needs a geometry parameter... which you are not sending it

Comment: The error is in the browser "Cannot read property 'scene' of undefined" and it tells me that it comes from this line "this.scene.add(loadedObject);"

Comment: it means it's a problem with the `this` in `this.scene`. Try using an arrow function. I will update my answer 1 more time.

Comment: I suggest you try some more simple javascript tutorials to get a better understanding and to understand how to interpret errors.

Comment: Thank you Mr 2pha. Now no error but still no 3d model and I am getting warnings like this in the browser THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "</html>" THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<div id="app"></div>"

Comment: What is happening is that the loader is returning html instead of the 3d image

Comment: Updated the code now with MTLLoader and the errors I am getting. Thank you so far for your time Mr 2pha

Comment: you can't add the material to the scene like that.. you should call setMaterials on the OBJloader with what is loaded from the MTLloader. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380403/how-to-use-objloader-and-mtlloader-in-three-js-r74-and-later). If the OBJloader is getting html, then the path is probably wrong, use the browser developer console network tab to debug it. You are going to have to learn how to debug yourself..... And now that you have changed this question 4 or 5 times, both the question and my answer have little value to anyone else on stack.

Comment: If you need to know how things work... the [three.js docs are here](https://threejs.org/docs/). The [three.js source code is here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). Plenty of [three.js examples here](https://threejs.org/examples/). Please try to debug yourself before asking questions.

Comment: Thank you for all the info Mr 2pha. I edited the initial question so people could see the actual situation and I did try to debug myself before every question. I guess that my knowledge with how vue cli3 works is still not enough to understand why certain bugs happen